# Python, Regex extract from string just working with numbers not letters

Tags: python, regex

I'm extracting id's from a url using regex.

It is working for the numeric id's, but NOT working for id's such "aa".

For instance, this doesn't work:

```
http://TESTETESTE/?s_device=m&bm_campaign=aa&utm_affiliate&b
```

but this does:

```
http://TESTETESTE/?s_device=m&bm_campaign=301103863&bf_adgroup
```

My code is:

```
df["id"] = df['captureurl'].str.extract('campaign=(\d+)')
```

Comment: that's because `\d` only matches digits... Why not use `'campaign=([A-Za-z0-9]+)'` or equivalently, `'campaign=([^\W_]+)'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `\d` matches "any decimal digit; this is equivalent to the class `[0-9]`" (quoting from https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/regex.html#matching-characters).

If you instead use `(\d|\w)` (`\w` "matches any alphanumeric character; this is equivalent to the class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`"). or just expand it: `[a-zA-z0-9]`, it'll match `aa` fine:

```
df["id"] = df['captureurl'].str.extract('bm_campaign=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)')
```